# Groovy: No signature of method: static java.lang.String.ValueOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [1572245927833]

Tags: java, groovy, jsr223

I'm kind of new to Groovy and now rework JS script to Groovy in JMeter. I've got persistent error `No signature of method: static java.lang.String.ValueOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [1572245927833]` when run in code below in JSR223 Groovy in JMeter, the error for line number with return statement:

```
def clientTransactionIdGen() {
    String timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
    def rand = get_random(1000000, 9999999);
    def user_id = vars.get("user_id");
    return timestamp + String.valueOf(rand) + '^' + user_id;
}
```

1572245927833 is time in seconds (so timestamp variable) and there is no ValueOf() conversion in line with return statement. I even changed timestamp type from `def` to `String`, still error points to line with `return` statement. Why such error in such place? As I understand there is a try to convert already string object to String. Why? The same error actually is when I have timestamp as long and convert in return line, also a puzzle to me:

```
def clientTransactionIdGen() {
    def timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    def rand = get_random(1000000, 9999999);
    def user_id = vars.get("user_id");
    return String.valueOf(timestamp) + String.valueOf(rand) + '^' + user_id;
}
```

ADDED: per good remarks changed all ValueOf to valueOf in all script, still the error as above stays and says: `No signature of method: static java.lang.String.ValueOf()`

ADDED: solved after reload of JMeter, apparently something remained cached and did not allow for proper debugging.

Comment: It says you are trying to parse a String to a String, which is pointless. Change String.ValueOf(rand) into simply rand

Comment: @michalk if that was the problem, he would already get errors on the timestamp parsing.

Comment: `String.ValueOf()` -> `String.valueOf()`: it's case-sensitive

Comment: @ernest_k, I've changed ValueOf to valueOf in the function - still same error

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov No way. Maybe something is cached or wasn't recompiled. Your error can't be reproduced. `String.valueOf` takes `Object`, so this error can't be justified.

Comment: @ernest_k, I unchecked cache tickmark in JMeter, still same error, give me several minutes I will make another short script to test your suggestion.

Comment: @ernest_k, after app (JMeter) reload error is no longer there, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java methods start with lower case [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)):

```
return timestamp + String.valueOf(rand) + '^' + user_id;
```

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov error can't remain `ValueOf`, maybe you have more code using `ValueOf` instead of `valueOf`

Comment: thank you, following @ernest_k remark of cached, I restarted and error went away.